# iMac keyboard stops working

Tags: keyboard, wifi, imac, bluetooth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wireless Keyboard disconnects](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35095/wireless-keyboard-disconnects)

The wireless Apple keyboard that came with my iMac has a tendency to suddenly disconnect from my iMac without no sensible reason (its not the battery). The only solution I have found this far is restarting the iMac, which automatically reconnects the keyboard. I have tried reconnecting the keyboard through the bluetooth configuration, which gives no ohther result than making the toolbar freeze.

Any solutions?

Comment: Workaround: Switch to the Finder, click in the `Search` field, and type. Text will appear. Then switch back to your app and all is well. This has worked for me many times on different Macs with different versions of macOS and with different keyboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have another Mac you can connect the keyboard to? If you can isolate whether or not this issue occurs only with your iMac or only with your iMacs keyboard, you can figure out where things are going wrong. Let us know if you're able to test the keyboard on another Mac or test the Mac with a different keyboard.

If you don't have access to either of those things, I'd recommend taking a trip to your local Apple Store and having them test it out. They'll have extra Macs and keyboard and a Bluetooth diagnostic to run as well.

Comment: Sadly i do not have access to another iMac, nor is there any Apple stores in my country (Norway). We do have authorized resellers though, do you know if they are able to take care of such problems as well?

Comment: If they are a authorized reseller, they may or may not be able to help you. The best bet is to find an Apple Authorized Service Provider. Either way, I would call ahead to see if they can help you.